Wasserstein distance of push-forward measures
I asked this same question on MSE, but with no luck, so I am trying to ask here.
Consider two measures $\mu , \nu$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Now consider a map (a priori only measurable, but feel free to add some regularity if you need) $f$ and the push forward measures $f_\# \mu, f_\# \nu$. Is there any estimate between the Wasserstein distance (say, 1-Wasserstein) between $\mu, \nu$ and the Wasserstein distance between $f_\# \mu, f_\# \nu$  other than $W(f_\# \mu , f_\# \nu) \leq Lip(f) W(\mu, \nu)$ if $f$ is Lipschitz? Also, is the optimal transport plan $\pi$ between $\mu$ and $\nu$ related to the optimal transport plan $\pi'$ between $f_\# \mu$ and $f_\# \nu$? I would be more interested in the case where $\mu$ and $\nu$ are diffuse, but anything is useful.

For this, you need conditions on $f$, say a Lipschitz condition.

@IosifPinelis do you perhaps know some counterexample that shows that, if $f$ is not Lipschitz, we can say nothing on the distance between $f_# \mu, f_# \nu$? Or do you at least believe this to be true?

Your comment is unclear to me. There is no such thing as "we can say nothing on". About any object A, we can always say "A is A".

@IosifPinelis I mean if using the Lipschitz constant on $f$ is the only known (at leat, well known) way to estimate the distance between the two push-forward measures, not requiring anything specific on $\mu$ and $\nu$

I think your post should be edited to make the question specific. "[A]ny relation" is very non-specific. The best would be to state your question formally. Also, there should be only one question in one post.

$\newcommand\R{\Bbb R}$

Is there any estimate between the Wasserstein distance (say, 1-Wasserstein) between $\mu, \nu$ and the Wasserstein distance between $f_\# \mu, f_\# \nu$  other than $W(f_\# \mu , f_\# \nu) \leq Lip(f) W(\mu, \nu)$ if $f$ is Lipschitz?

Yes. More generally, suppose that $f$ satisfies the Hölder condition
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\le C|x-y|^a$$
for some real $C\ge0$, some $a\in(0,1]$, and all $x$ and $y$ in $\R^n$, where $|\cdot|$ is the Euclidean norm.
Then for any random vectors $X$ and $Y$ in $\R^n$ with respective distributions $\mu$ and $\nu$,
$$E|f(X)-f(Y)|\le CE|X-Y|^a\le C(E|X-Y|)^a,$$
whence
$$W_1(f_{\#}\mu,f_{\#}\nu)\le CW_1(\mu,\nu)^a.$$
